# WebView doesn't show image

Tags: android, android-widget

I have WebView in myLayout and I am trying to load html string like  ( I receive html in string data ) like

```
tempWebView.loadData(htmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

inside htmlString there is img tag with src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e3/Flag_of_Papua_New_Guinea.svg" for example. Problem is that in emulator temWebView shows content of string and image but on phone there is no image ( default icon for missing image is there) but text content is there. What is problem, do I need to set some flag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android's version of WebKit does not support SVG, AFAIK.